# Why is my UTM campaign name in Journey builder locked

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, google-analytics, email-tracking

I am trying to changing the name of the UTM campaign name in journey builder but is is locked. How do I change / modify this?
[image: UTM]

Answer (score 0):

While setting up GA360 tracking parameters, we set up UTM parameters for tracking purpose like utm_source, utm_medium, utm_campaign, etc. We have 2 values to configure for utm_campaign:

1. {{Message Name}} - It will pull the actual email name from content builder
2. {{Set per Message}} - You can set dynamic name for emails.

utm_campaign field is disabled because {{Message Name}} is configured in setup. All you need to do is change this setting to {{Set per Message}} in Setup to have custom/dynamic name. Below are the steps to do so:

Navigate to Setup -> Data Management -> Parameter Management -> Goggle Analytics Tracking -> Edit -> Change utm_campaign to {{Set per Message}} for 'Email'.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thank you for a helpful contribution - please continue to be active on SFSE.